# Doctrine 2.1.6 Reverse Engineering 1-n (one to many) association misunderstood as 1-1 (one to one)

Tags: php, sql, orm, doctrine-orm

I found an odd behaviour of Doctrine's reverse engineering process, just create two simple tables tied by a simple 1-n relationship, take a look at the snap of the folowing SQL code:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `ACME` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ACME` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `ACME` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ACME`.`task`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACME`.`task` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ACME`.`task` (
  `id_task` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_task`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ACME`.`tag`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACME`.`tag` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ACME`.`tag` (
  `id_tag` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `task_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tag`) ,
  INDEX `fk_tag_task` (`task_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tag_task`
    FOREIGN KEY (`task_id` )
    REFERENCES `ACME`.`task` (`id_task` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I have a Symfony2 netbeans project at

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Acme

and from that location, according to

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

in a terminal I did:

```
$ ./../../bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ --from-database --force
Processing entity "Tag"
Processing entity "Task"

Exporting "yml" mapping information to "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Acme/src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/doctrine"

$ ./../../bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php app/console doctrine:mapping:import Acme\TaskBundle yml
Importing mapping information from "default" entity manager
  > writing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Acme/src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Tag.orm.yml
  > writing /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Acme/src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Task.orm.yml

$ ./../../bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme\TaskBundle
Generating entities for bundle "AcmeTaskBundle"
  > backing up Tag.php to Tag.php~
  > generating Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag
  > backing up Task.php to Task.php~
  > generating Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task
```

The fact is that it only seems ok, because if you take a look at "Tag.orm.yml":

```
Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag:
  type: entity
  table: tag
  fields:
    idTag:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_tag
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
      fixed: false
      nullable: true
  oneToOne:
    task:
      targetEntity: Task
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
        task_id:
          referencedColumnName: id_task
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

It created a **oneToOne** relationship and not a **oneToMany** !

If you need any more confirmation, here are ***Task.php*** and ***Tag.php***:

***Task.php***

```
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @var integer $idTask
     */
    private $idTask;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * Get idTask
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdTask()
    {
        return $this->idTask;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

***Tag.php***

```
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer $idTag
     */
    private $idTag;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task
     */
    private $task;


    /**
     * Get idTag
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdTag()
    {
        return $this->idTag;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set task
     *
     * @param Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $task
     */
    public function setTask(\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task $task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    /**
     * Get task
     *
     * @return Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task 
     */
    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }
}
```

Do you guys have met this problem too?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe it's a bug, so I posted it in the Symfony's issues page.

Comment: Has anyone encountered this bug? Am I the only and lonely poor guy who met it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a critical discovery: using xml instead of yml in the first command, the one with doctrine:mapping:convert, IT WORKS IN THE RIGHT WAY.

Goddamned stupid bug.

Linuxatico